# Does a finitely generated group $G$, ever act on $G/N$ freely?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, free-groups, finitely-generated

Say that $G$ is a finitely generated group on $k \geq 2$ generators and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I want to know if I can construct a $G$-action on $G/N$ such that the action is free. None of the usual actions such as left-multiplication, conjugation are going to work.

Are there any conditions that will allow me to construct a free $G$-action? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are examples in which $N$ is nontrivial and $G/N \cong G$ (when $G$ is a *nonHopfian* group), in which case you can use the standard free action coming from Cayley's Theorem.

Comment: Or, more crudely, provided that $G$ and $G/N$ are both infinite, they are both countably infinite, and so you can defined a free action of $G$ on$G/N$ using an arbitrary bijection between them, but then the action will having nothing to do with the group structure of $G/N$.

Comment: Derek's comment shows that you need to be more specific about your question (what kind of action do you want?) Highlighting relevant hypotheses precisely helps converging to the right way to ask questions, and even helps solving them.

Comment: On the other extreme, suppose that cardinality of $G/N$ is less than the cardinality of $G$. Then you cannot find a free action.